# IM slang expressions in textmessages

Tags: argot

Je cherche la traduction pour les textos ci-dessous.

1) ChepEpa, chui KC et NRV. G tro boC.

2) Tu vi1 pr l'APro? Yaskifo!

3)

```
    P                       6
  _____         à        ______
  venez                    100
```

4) ErE o jE, malErE in love.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

c'est plus du phonétique (les lettres majuscules remplacent des syllabes) que de l'argot. Je dirais :

1) Je ne peux pas, je suis cassé (=épuisé) et énervé. J'ai trop bossé (=travaillé)

2) Tu viens pour l'apéro ? Il y a tout ce qu'il faut.

3) Venez souper (=come for dinner) à [Sanssouci](http://www.chateausanssouci.fr/) (it was a Palace in the past). It is a known "Rébus", which is said to be from *Voltaire* to *Frédéric II* ([source](http://sindelaar.blogspot.fr/2005/10/les-sms-de-voltaire-et-frdric-ii.html))

4) Heureux au jeu, malheureux en amour.

Comment: pour rajouter la 3ème (qui est un rébus...) : "venez souper (=manger) [à "sans soucis"] ou [assis sur cens]" (la 2ème partie est assez obscure, car si c'est un nom propre, ça peut être n'importe quoi...)

Comment: merci, j'ai complété. sans soucis est le plus plausible

Comment: En effet, le "sanssouci" est en endroit connu apparement (le [Palais de Sanssouci](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palais_de_Sanssouci)). On trouve également cette traduction [ici](http://www.arte.tv/fr/le-rebus-sanssouci/3069066,CmC=3069074.html).